# hide and show a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question, I'm making a javascript that shows and hide a div by clicking another div but because divs don't have a value or a name I can't find out a way to do this.
I'm using input type hidden because it can have a value, but still it doesn't work as it should.
I hope somebody can help me to find a solution thanks!

```js
function hideshow(pairsblock){
   var value = document.getElementById(pairheader).value;
    if(value == 1){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(pairheader).value = 2;    
    }else if(value == 2){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(pairheader).value = 1;              
    }    
}
```

```css
.box {
border :2px solid #0f111d82;
margin-left :10px !important;
margin-right :10px !important;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color: #0f111d82;

}
```

```html
  <div id="pairheader2" onclick="hideshow('pairsblock')" class="box">
      <input type="hidden" id="pairheader" value="1">
          <h6>header</h6>
  </div>
    
<div id="pairsblock" class="pairs-block">
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: They dont have a value but they can have data- attributes. You can use them

Comment: Thanks! you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `pairheader` plainly so javascript expects a variable. The variable isn't defined, so it errors. `document.getElementById()` takes a string as it's paramater

```js
function hideshow(pairsblock){
   var value = document.getElementById('pairheader').value;
    if(value == 1){
        document.getElementById('pairsblock').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('pairheader').value = 2;    
    }else if(value == 2){
        document.getElementById('pairsblock').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('pairheader').value = 1;              
             }    
}
```

```css
.box {
border :2px solid #0f111d82;
margin-left :10px !important;
margin-right :10px !important;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color: #0f111d82;

}
```

```html
<div id="pairheader2" onclick="hideshow('pairsblock')" class="box">
      <input type="hidden" id="pairheader" value="1">
          <h6>header</h6>
  </div>
    
<div id="pairsblock" class="pairs-block">
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You code is throwing `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"` because `document.getElementById(pairheader)`, as `pairheader` variable is not defined.

`id` of input field is not a variable but a string, you have forgot to wrap it in `""`. So in your code `pairheader` should instead be `"pairheader"`.

```js
function hideshow(pairsblock){
   var value = document.getElementById("pairheader").value;
    if(value == 1){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("pairheader").value = 2;    
    }else if(value == 2){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("pairheader").value = 1;              
             }    
}
```

```css
.box {
border :2px solid #0f111d82;
margin-left :10px !important;
margin-right :10px !important;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color: #0f111d82;

}
```

```html
<div id="pairheader2" onclick="hideshow('pairsblock')" class="box">
      <input type="hidden" id="pairheader" value="1">
          <h6>header</h6>
  </div>
    
<div id="pairsblock" class="pairs-block">
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code.

You are using `pairsblock` as a parameter. It's ok.

But what about `pairheader` ? You are using it in plain.

First you need to learn about how parameters are used in functions. Then **[document.getElementById('someId')](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)**.

```js
function hideshow(pairsblock){
   var value = document.getElementById('pairheader').value;
    if(value == 1){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('pairheader').value = 2;    
    }else if(value == 2){
        document.getElementById(pairsblock).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('pairheader').value = 1;              
             }    
}
```

```css
.box {
border :2px solid #0f111d82;
margin-left :10px !important;
margin-right :10px !important;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color: #0f111d82;

}
```

```html
<div id="pairheader2" onclick="hideshow('pairsblock')" class="box">
      <input type="hidden" id="pairheader" value="1">
          <h6>header</h6>
  </div>
    
<div id="pairsblock" class="pairs-block">
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

*If have Jquery in your application and if you are ok to use it*, you can use it and use its toggle method to simple hide and show the pairsblock div using its id.

```js
function hideshow(pairsblock){
   $('#pairsblock').toggle()  
}
```

```css
.box {
border :2px solid #0f111d82;
margin-left :10px !important;
margin-right :10px !important;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:15px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-right:5px;
background-color: #0f111d82;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pairheader2" onclick="hideshow('pairsblock')" class="box">
      <input type="hidden" id="pairheader" value="1">
          <h6>header</h6>
  </div>
    
<div id="pairsblock" class="pairs-block">
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: There is no reason to load jQuery, a huge library, to do such a simple task. It's literally just 6 lines.

Comment: Its not a compulsion. I just added if he is ok to use jquery (I am not sure if he is currently doing it).